# If I do not have a photocopy of a magic item to give my PCs, what are my options for AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

In AL when a player leaves a table they are allowed to sometimes take an item with them from table to table. Now if they do not have a decent phone to take a picture, cannot photocopy, a printout isn't available, or etc., is it acceptable to allow a fully well written index card of the item along with page number from the hardcover book as an alternative? Everything else, such as a provided DCI number of DM and session log to further prove this is all legit, is a given in this.

Comment: Magic items are not "gifts" in AL. You should probably reword the question.

Answer (score 7):

### All you need to do is properly log the item.

Certificates, photos, [photocopies](https://youtu.be/PZbqAMEwtOE), and the like are all just optional ways of providing this logging function. Here're the relevant rules-references:

AL DMG (circa SKT) p.6, emphasis mine:

> Permanent magic items are
> distributed at the conclusion of a session, episode,
> or adventure. **A player notes the item obtained by
> recording it on their logsheet.** Permanent magic
> items have specific rules for distribution to promote
> equity. Each character’s logsheet contains a column
> to record permanent magic items for ease of
> reference. Follow these steps to determine how to
> distribute permanent magic items. [Rules for choosing who gets an item, items with charges, &c. follow.]

[AL FAQ v3.0](http://dndadventurersleague.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/DDAL-FAQ-v3.0.pdf) [in the context of magic items with add'l properties], emphasis mine:

> Your DMs should remember to provide the full item
> description to their players, and/or provide
> photographs or photocopies of each item for their
> players. **It is your responsibility to make sure that
> you keep accurate track of any additional properties
> in your adventure logsheet.**

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: it just needs to be written down.**

> Is it acceptable to allow a fully well written index card of the item along with page number from the hardcover book as an alternative?

Absolutely, however, I do this one of two ways.

For AL-specific content from the DM's Guild site, I first try to print the item cards that come with the adventure. Only works for Season 5+, but it's there.

For hardcovers, I typically print my own in advance. But when that's not an option (*especially with random items in SKT*), then the index card is fine. But to make everyone's life easier, I would include the following:

- Item name, rarity, attunement
- Item description (*some items are specifically described*)
- Item abilities
- DM DCI number
- Date found
- Adventure & Room Number found
- For random items, you must also list the table + die roll

If you flip it around, what information would **you** like from a random player that shows up at your table? Probably the stuff I just listed. We don't need to be fancy, just thorough :)